# Groupby gives me an additional level of indices

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains rankings on a group level:

```
       foo  rank
year            
2000    10   340
2000  7010   134
2000  7000   135
2000  6940    83
2000  6840    82
2000  6830    19
2000  6820    81
2000  6800   162
2000  6765   161
2000  7020   136
```

I wrote a function that clusters rankings by some arbitrary `n`. For `n=2`, that is equivalent for grouping the upper 50% of ranks together, and the lower 50%:

```
def createRankGroups(group, n):
    maxRank = group['rank'].max()
    group['group'] = np.nan
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        upperRankBoundary = maxRank / n * i
        idx = (group['rank'] <= upperRankBoundary) & group.group.isnull()
        group.loc[idx, 'group'] = i
    return group['group']
```

The problem is that when I use `apply` to use this function, I get an unneeded level of indices back, which ruins the merging.

```
df['group'] = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: createRankGroups(x, 2))
Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

And this is why:

```
In[42]: df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: createRankGroups(x, 2)).head()
Out[42]: 
year  year
2000  2000    2
      2000    1
      2000    1
      2000    1
      2000    1
```

I thought that perhaps this was caused by indices being non-unique (since I was not passing along `foo`, so I tried that as well:

```
In[43]: df = df.reset_index().set_index(['year', 'foo'])
In[44]: df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: createRankGroups(x, 2)).head()
Out[44]: 
year  year  foo 
2000  2000  10      2
            7010    1
            7000    1
            6940    1
            6840    1
```

Finally, also enforcing sorting on the index by `df.sort_index(level=0, inplace=True)` didnt solve the issue. What can I do?

Comment: I know I could just `.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)`, but I'm after the reason of why this doesnt work (and what the proper way of doing it is)

Comment: But I'm getting a `DF` in a wide format with both `index` and `column` names corresponding to the year 2000 after performing `df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: createRankGroups(x, 2))` and not in the long format as yours?